# C# How to check string array elements is in string starting?

Tags: c#

I have a string arrary. Lets say as below

```
string[] lists = { "one", "two", "three"};
```

I have a string. Lets say as below

```
string title = "ONE_Page1";
```

I want to check, whether any of the **array elements** (lists) contains in my **string *starting*** (title).

Comment: Is 'title' always in that format with "_" that separates part of the string that has to be compared ?

Comment: no, it may be having spaces like "ONE Page1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always some hate for the [Array.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yw84x8be(v=vs.110).aspx) functions, so here there is my variant :-)

```
string[] lists = { "one", "two", "three"};
string title = "ONE_Page1";

bool existsContain = Array.Exists(lists, x => title.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1);

bool existsStartsWith = Array.Exists(lists, x => title.StartsWith(x, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

It isn't clear if you want to match `xxx_one_yyy` (the fist one does it) or only "starts with" (so only `one_yyy`) (the second one does it)

Note that instead of [StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you could use [StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), depending on how you want your app to behave with internationalization.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to check if any string in the list is a substring of your "main-string"?

```
bool contains = lists
    .Any(s => title.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

If you don't want to compare case-insensitively you could use [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is more readable. But your sample data suggests that you want to compare case-insensitive.

Comment: Hi Tim, You are right. at the same time. I need to check my main string starts with any of the list items.

Comment: @user1428019: `IndexOf` also works at the beginning, so it checks if the _main-string_ "contains" any of the strings in the list at any place(so also at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

You can use some simple LINQ:

```
string[] lists = { "one", "two", "three"};
string title = "ONE_Page1";
bool titleStartsWithAnElementInLists = lists.Any(
    prefix => title.StartsWith(prefix, true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I guess that `StartsWith` is not appropriate since OP mentioned `contains`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Quite possibly :) The wording of the question is a bit ambiguous, I took it that 'contains' referred to the array elements, not the string, but perhaps that wasn't the intention.